# Latex3 equivalent of \two@digits

Tags: latex3

I am trying to create LaTeX3 equivalent of `\two@digits`. Here is what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

%% Write a 0 for #1 is < 10
\cs_new:Nn \__erc_twodigits:N
  {
    \int_compare:nNnTF { #1 } < { 10 } { 0 } { } #1
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\typeset} { }
  {
    \__erc_twodigits:N \c_sys_month_int
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\typeset

\end{document}
```

Now `\c_sys_month_int` should expand to an integer, and the whole construction should be expanded to `08` (for August). I would like this expansion to be written to a file with `\iow_now`. `\typeset` is only here to supply a user land function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're just missing an `\int_use:N` in your code (if the integer is guaranteed to be greater or equal to zero).

I also added an `n`-type variant using `\int_eval:n` like suggested by [@JosephWright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/609441/latex3-equivalent-of-twodigits/609444#comment1524641_609444).

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

%% Write a 0 for #1 is < 10
\cs_new:Npn \__erc_twodigits:N #1
  {
    \int_compare:nNnT #1 < { 10 } { 0 } \int_use:N #1
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__erc_twodigits:n #1
  {
    \int_compare:nNnT {#1} < { 10 } { 0 } \int_eval:n {#1}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\typeset} { }
  {
    \__erc_twodigits:N \c_sys_month_int
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\typeset

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to make it `n`-type and use `\int_eval:n`

Comment: @JosephWright so was I :)

Comment: Since he's trying to recreate the existing `\two@digits`, it meets the constraints of that command. Of course, if the end goal is to write to a file, then `\typeset` (or its equivalent) should be defined with `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` or else the write will put out `\typeset` and not its expansion (and also he should use `\iow_now:Nx` for the output.

Comment: @DonHosek I interpreted "`\typeset` is only here to supply a user land function."  as though OP knows that this would be necessary.

Comment: Fair enough, but it's stlil worth noting, especially for future visitors to the q&a

Comment: @Skillmon I think that Joseph's idea was to get rid of `\__erc_twodigits:N`, so it's immaterial if `#1` is an explicit integer or an “internal” integer.

Comment: @egreg I know, but I kept the original variant as that shows what exactly is missing from OP's code, and added the second variant to show what I'd have done.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a generic padding macro that takes as argument any integer (explicit or implicit) and adds zeros at the beginning (if the number of digits is less than what requested) and keeps a possible minus sign at the beginning.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \jodb_ndigits:nn
  { % #1 = number of digits, #2 = integer
    \int_compare:nT { #2 < 0 } { - }
    \prg_replicate:nn
      {
        \int_max:nn { #1 - \str_count:e { \int_abs:n { #2 } } } { 0 }
      }
     {
       0
     }
    \int_abs:n { #2 }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_count:n { e }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\padding}{O{2}m}
  {
    \jodb_ndigits:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\padding[2]{\month}

\padding[3]{1234}

\padding[3]{-\month}

\padding[2]{0}

\edef\test{\padding[4]{\day}}
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is to stringify the absolute value of the integer and add zeros if needed.

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer.